# How to make child element width 30 precent of parent elements width using css?

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```css
#edj{
 width:50%;
 border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "edj">
<p><label>Faculty <input type="text" class = "k"> </label></p>
<p><label >Departmet <input type="text" class = "k"> </label>
</div>
```

I want to make textboxes width 30 percent of the div width.

How can I implement this using css code?

Comment: is it ok to nest an input element inside a label tag?

Comment: @David: yes. Yes, it is ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)); it avoids having to give each associated `<input>` an `id` and each `<label>` a `for`. I am confused as to why the `<label>` is itself wrapped in a paragraph, though; that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an answer in it's simplest form, this will make input fields 30% of parents width.

```
input {
    width: 30%;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to assign the width for the input using CSS `width`.

Example:

```
   #edj input { width:30%;}
```

This assigns all input tags **within the `#edj` parent** to be exactly 30% of the parent div.

---

```css
#edj{
 width:50%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
}

#edj input { width:30%;}
```

```html
<div id = "edj">
<p><label>Faculty <input type="text" class = "k"> </label></p>
<p><label >Departmet <input type="text" class = "k"> </label>
</div>
```